# Notification action button does not fire pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I try to send intent to BroadcastReceiver from notification action button my problem is that when I click the button the intent in not fired or not getting to the BroadcastReceiver.

Here is my code:

The notification:

```
Intent accept = new Intent(this, ChallengesActionReceiver.class);
accept.setAction("com.soinfit.utilities.CHALLENGE_CLICK");
accept.putExtra("reqId", extras.getString("reqId"));
accept.putExtra("answer", "1");       
PendingIntent acceptIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, accept, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

.setLargeIcon(image)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_small)
.setContentTitle("soInFit")
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
.bigText(msg))
.setAutoCancel(true)
.addAction(R.drawable.app_icon_small, getString(R.string.accept), acceptIntent)
.setContentText(msg);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

Notification nof = mBuilder.getNotification();

nof.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
nof.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
nof.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

nof.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(id+1, nof);
```

The BroadcastReceiver

```
public class ChallengesActionReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver

{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Log.i("test", "test");
}

}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="utilities.ChallengesActionReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >

     <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.soinfit.utilities.CHALLENGE_CLICK" />     
       </intent-filter>
```

If I call this code:

```
    Intent accept = new Intent(this, ChallengesActionReceiver.class);
    accept.setAction("com.soinfit.utilities.CHALLENGE_CLICK");
    accept.putExtra("reqId", extras.getString("reqId"));
    accept.putExtra("answer", "1");       
    PendingIntent acceptIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, accept, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

this.sendBroadcast(accept);
```

Its working fine.

Answer (score 6):

I had to change

```
PendingIntent.getActivity
```

to

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast
```

Comment: This, and check the android:name of your receiver in your manifest - is utilities the entire package name, or should it be .utilities.ChallengesActionReceiver?

Comment: @dasdasd what changes have you made? i am facing the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Use method .setContentIntent(), instead of .addAction() to launch pending intent.

Comment: Its not the case. I dont want to fire when the content clicked only when my button clicked.